# I need the code to autosave copies in google sheets when closing an invoice template i have made -

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need the code to autosave copies in google sheets when closing an invoice template i have made - to save it based on the invoice number and to reopen to a new invoice with the invoice number increased by 1

i am including a link to the sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b4saYo1ruVfpUbUsGVd0Vf3NmjwQo78riuMyWi0OFcg/edit?usp=sharing

there are formulae sitting in the sheet which should not be changed.

i just need to be able to have the code for a button that i can click and it closes the current sheet at the same time saving it as a pdf in an online location and when i reopen the invoice number has increased by 1

Comment: Welcome. Would you please summarise the research that you did before you posted your question.

Answer (score 0):

## What you have:

- Each sheet is an invoice with a number

## What you want:

- Trigger a new blank invoice to appear

  - This new invoice needs to have a unique number = `previous number` + 1

## To accomplish this you will have to:

- Get the current sheet (the current invoice)
- Copy the sheet

  - I would suggest renaming it to the invoice number for easier finding
- Update the current invoice number.
- Delete the old invoice contents on the original sheet (previously referred to as current sheet)

## Step-by-step

### Preliminary Setup

I've made [a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHFNdOGT7CccOKOfsl_aIsAkQl0iTc-KawNzzSvvgVY/edit?usp=sharing) based on the sheet you provided. I did some modifications like removing the extra columns and rows to make life easier.

Based on this copy, let's store some information about our sheet into a variable.

On out Apps Script code for that sheet, let's write:

```
const fieldsA1 = {
  invoiceNumber : "F5",
  salesperson : "A14" //As an example of a field we want to clear later
};


function generateNewInvoice() {
}
```

### Get the current sheet

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //Gets the current spreadsheet file
var currentInvoice = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Get the open Sheet (the current invoice)
```

### Copy the sheet

```
var copyInvoice = spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet(); //Creates a copy of currentInvoice and assign it to copyInvoice
```

#### Rename and style the new sheet

In this case I chose to style the new sheet in the following format:

[image: Example output]

```
copyInvoice.setName("Invoice " + currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.invoiceNumber).getValue());
copyInvoice.setTabColor("red"); //For example, to highlight the tab
```

### Update the current invoice number

```
var newInvoiceNumber = Number(currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.invoiceNumber).getValue())+1; //Gets a new invoice number by adding 1 to the current Invoice Number
currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.invoiceNumber).setValue(newInvoiceNumber);
```

### Delete the old contents from the original sheet

```
//Other operations that might be interesting for your invoice
currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.salesperson).clear(); //Reset salesperson
```

## Final result

```
const fieldsA1 = {
  invoiceNumber : "F5",
  salesperson : "A14" //As an example of a field we want to clear later
};


function generateNewInvoice() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //Gets the current spreadsheet file
  var currentInvoice = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Get the open Sheet (the current invoice)
  var copyInvoice = spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet(); //Creates a copy of currentInvoice and assign it to copyInvoice
  copyInvoice.setName("Invoice " + currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.invoiceNumber).getValue());
  copyInvoice.setTabColor("red"); //For example, to highlight the tab

  var newInvoiceNumber = Number(currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.invoiceNumber).getValue())+1; //Gets a new invoice number by adding 1 to the current Invoice Number
  currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.invoiceNumber).setValue(newInvoiceNumber);


  //Other operations that might be interesting for your invoice
  currentInvoice.getRange(fieldsA1.salesperson).clear(); //Reset salesperson
}
```

Now it's just a matter of triggering the `generatedNewInvoice` function from the sheet. You could do this with a [toolbar action](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createmenucaption), for example.